# No sound w/Ubuntu

Tags: sound, 19.10, raspberrypi

I really need help with a sound issue I have.
I have little to no knowledge on how to do things on Ubuntu so I have no clue on how to get sound working. It doesn't acknowledge that there is a audio port on the board. (I am using Pi 4, 4 GB)

Comment: version 19.10.1

Comment: Version of what is 19.10.1?

Comment: Ubuntu desktop i believe

Comment: There never was 19.10.1 version of Ubuntu desktop.